# JPA save another Time into database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, time

I have encountered problem in using JPA to save Time type into database.
Time value from browser into Java is mapped correctly, but when JPA save the value into DB, it become a different value.
Is there any solution to save time into database without changing the data of time?
(I have only 2 solutions: Change Time type into long or string, but I still prefer the solution that can save Time value).

- Data input in browser:
  [Data input in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad2iB.png)
- Save before save into DB:
  [Data before save into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZwaQ.png)
- The data save into database(I use MySQL). I change value from 11:00:00 to 04:00:00:
  [Data when save into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUNrA.png)

Comment: check that the timezones for all three systems are consitent

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are trying to use timestamp (which actually represents a time point) field for duration (which represents time interval) purposes.

When you enter 11:00 it might means 11:00 at PST, UTC, ICT timezones. And these will be absolutely different values.

Instead of java.util.Date in java you have to use java.time.Duration and use TIME field in MySQL (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But finally, I still need to convert Duration into String or Long because JPA doesnot automatically convert Duration into Time value

Comment: Yeah... It's a pretty usual way how this happened with duration fields. Since jdbc doesn't have a good support for this field and some databases don't have this field type out of box - the long field is pretty common solution.